# JSONLoader vs ObjectLoader, whats the difference? (three.js)

Tags: three.js

i'm currently using the JSONLoader for all my loading, but i'm wondering what the ObjectLoader is all about, and what the difference between it and the JSONloader is. Both presumably load .js files from what i read (and from the extent i've used the JSONloader), but apparently the objectloader is more flexible? Are there any advantages to the ObjectLoader vs the JSONLoader? i can't really find much info.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the exactly difference. You can check it by your own if you compare the .js-Files:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/loaders

I think the ObjectLoader is the new, faster one but idk if this is true. The JSONLoader was updatet a half year in the past, the ObjectLoader 2 month ago.

EDIT:

If you cant compare them tell me, then I start to check booth .js-Files and can tell you exactly what they do and what is the difference.